# How multi-dimensional arrays are represented in memory

Tags: memory, multidimensional-array, representation

As memory is considered to be single dimensional, then can anyone kindly tell (and explain) that "How multi-dimesional arrays are represented in Memory".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the language implementation but more often than not they are represented as a consecutive memory block row after row. 
I wrote about it on [my blog](http://blog.drorhelper.com/2009/04/performance-optimization-tip-understand.html):

> Allocated arrays are stored in the heap memory as a continues chunk of
>   memory. Two dimensional arrays (same as in the example above) are
>   stored similarly – each line of the array (index x,0 – x,n) stored
>   together and so to reach the x,y cell we have to go to the j + (i *
>   width) place.

For more details on hoiw arrays are implemented in C++ take a look at:
[C++ Notes: 2-D Array Memory Layout](http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-cpp/arrayptr/23two-dim-array-memory-layout.html)

Most of the programming languages I encoutered use a similar method to storing multidimensional arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Any multidimensional arrays are linearized by array addressing function and transforms the multidimensional arrays into a single dimensional array. This single dimensional arrays are stored on memory.